# char extraction issue with ZipFile (System.IO.Compression), c# (WPF)

Tags: c#, compression, zip, self-extracting

I am trying to extract a zip with multiple files. Some files have the "§" character in their names (*"abc(§7)abc.txt"*).
When unpacking,

```
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(string sourceArchiveFileName, string destinationDirectoryName);
```

however, the '§' character is translated into the 'õ' (Latin Small Letter O with Tilde) character.

I have already tried to change the encoding. But there is only ASCII or UTF-8 (default)

```
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(sourceArchiveFileName, destinationDirectoryName, Encoding entryNameEncoding);
```

Is someone able to show me the mistake?

Comment: I've been through a bunch of different encodings, and I can't find one where `§` has an encoding which is the same as the UTF-8 encoding of `õ`... In fact, the UTF-8 encoding of `õ` is 2 bytes: are you sure that only the single `§` character is being converted into `õ`, or might it be taking one of the `(` or `)` as well?

Comment: I had also searched for correlations, but found none.

It is only the single character that is translated.

Comment: I tried now a diffrent libary: ionic.Zip

The result:
this time i get "⌡" (Bottom Half Integral) instead "§"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows don't behave nicely with unicode file names inside zip.
Using the Enconding 850 solves the problem.

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(850);
```

It looks like it got fixed in .Net framework 4.8 but I can't test it right now.

Sources:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180515-00/?p=98755
http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2012/01/04/10252916.html

Comment: Thanks much! That helped.

Comment: Where can you see information about it being fixed in 4.8? None of the links mention it?